# Help with installing brother printer MFCJ270W

Tags: printing

I need help with installing my brother printer model: MFC-J270W. I found all of the required Linux drivers for this printer from the Brother website, I just need guidance on how to install this via terminal. I tried on my own but failed. Any help is appreciated. Here is the Brother website for my specific printer.

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-J270W

Brother MFC-J270W

Answer (score 0):

In 12.04, and in 11.10 and 11.04, simply clicking on the .deb file should open the package manager, where you just press the "install" button. but if you want to use the terminal, more power to you. I would the the cupswrapper.deb file. download it, and keep in mind where its saved. for this example, I saved it in my Downloads folder.

according to Brother, you have 1 dependencies, lets install them first in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

it might already be installed, but its good to check.
now to the .deb file. navigate to where you saved the file in your terminal. for me, thats my download folder:

```
cd /home/jmartin2279/Downloads
```

do and "ls" to verify you see the .deb
now type:

```
sudo dpkg -i cupswrapper.deb
```

and follow the onscreen instructions, if any.
thats it!

I dont know how long it will take to run the deb. I know HP drivers took about 10 minutes on my system, but it was a much larger file.